# Error "too many requests" al conectar varias hojas de cálculo de Google

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, powerbi, powerquery

Tengo un dashboard publicado en Power BI Service, el cual tiene conexión a 6 hojas de cálculo de Google Sheets. Este dashboard se actualiza cada 2 horas. Sin embargo, de vez en cuando me presenta el error "too many requests", por lo cual debo actualizarlo manualmente.

Habrá alguna forma de prevenir este error? No he encontrado como agregarle un tiempo de espera o algo parecido a las tablas que cargan las hojas de cálculo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.